# Install CentOS from hard drive - kernel panic

Tags: centos, dual-boot, system-installation

I want to dual-boot CentOS and Windows XP. The computer has two partitions (C: and D:) and I want to install CentOS 6.2 on the D: drive.

So I downloaded the i386 ISO package, used UNetbootin to deploy that ISO on the hard drive and booted to UNetbootin. After I select the Install CentOS option, I get the following

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
panic occured, switching back to text console
```

and nothing else.

Any advice? Please note that I don't have a CD Drive, and also I do not have any USB storage at hand.

Comment: Not really an answer, but it will be less of a hassle doing this with an USB drive and UNetBootin.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the CD's installer isn't able to detect the root of the original CD's disk.  I don't know why you're using UNetbootin, but it's clearly not designed to install CentOS.

Comment: @jsbillings You are most likely right. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @OmarAbid: try following the instructions on the CentOS Wiki to install from a USB device: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing CentOS from HDD is possible,  extract the ISO image onto your HDD, copy the syslinux config out, to e.g if you use `grub4dos` to load the installer.

Last time I managed to do this, by modifying the installer partly, which make it mount the ISO image instead of real CD, but it might be fixed already.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your hardware specifics it is difficult to really say why you are getting kernel panic.  If you are looking for another method in creating boot media without using a CD/DVD drive I would recommend pendrive Linux (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)  it's free software that I have had good luck with in the past.  (apologies if this isn't helpful due to no USB storage, I wasn't entirely sure from the post as unetbootin is used to create USB media).

Comment: The processor is an Atom 1.6GHZ, and the laptop has 1GB RAM and enough harddrive space. Isn't that enough?

Comment: What chipset is on the board that you are using?  From what I have seen in the past kernel panic is usually the result of a driver issue.  @Renan, wasn't so much of an answer, was wanting to leave a comment but didn't see the option to leave one on the post.